# Direct Object Reference Countermeasure Using MD5

Tags: security, object, hash, reference

I am trying to add some security features to my code to prevent Direct Object Reference attacks. Every user has a list of **projects**. When retrieved, each project is assigned a number starting at 1 that will be used for different functions (delete, updates, etc).

- 1 - Project 1 with ID of 67
- 2 - Project 2 with ID of 88
- 3 - Project 3 with ID of 90
- 4 - Project 4 with ID of 145

So, if a user wants to delete Project 3 - a DELETE request will be sent like this: **http://website.com/projects/3**. But, if they happen to send the request again, it will remove Project 4.

My fix was to hash the ID and send it as well. So, if a user wanted to delete Project 3, they would send **http://website.com/projects/3/hashOfId** which would then be checked against the Project ID before it deleted the item.

Is this safe, or is there an alternative that is a better practice? The ability for other users or the current user to be able to delete and change things at the same time is important. It is also important not to reveal the ID of the project. I haven't been able to find any examples online of other methods.

Thanks!

Comment: See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References - Use the actual project ID as the reference - this will solve your repeated request problem, but check access server side. Use POST requests as these will not be repeated by the browser or proxy server.

Comment: @SilverlightFox that's what I am doing now and I am fine with that! I just know a lot of people are saying that you should try to avoid direct relations.